# Understanding the use of 'eo' in a sentence from LLPSI

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

The usage of *eo* is somewhat confusing to me with this sentence:

> Medus prope Romam est; iam muri Romani ab eo videntur et porta Capena.

The first half is easy, however the second half is confusing to me because I'm not sure what *eo* is, and also because of the placement of *et porta Capena* at the end of the sentence. My initial thought was something like, "and from (here) he can see the walls of Rome and the gate of Capena".

Edit: Corrected *Roman* to *Romam*.

Answer (score 5):

It is a somewhat confusing sentence!

Hint: what other translation of *ab* do you know?

Second hint: what is the ending in *videntur*, and how do you translate it?

P.S. I think your *Roman* should be *Romam*?

Comment: The first meaning that comes to mind is "from", as in from a particular location, although I think it also can be from a cause. My understanding of "videntur" is it's the present tense, passive voice of "see", or something like that, so maybe something like "he is seeing". I fixed my typo (note to self: vodka does not help spelling).

Comment: @Adam: A cause is closer. But there is yet another translation, one that is common when the praedicate is passive. As to *videntur*, it is indeed passive. But what person, what number? *He is seeing* is not how the passive is translated, though; *videor* is "I am (being) seen". The person doing the seeing is not the subject.

Comment: Per the other answer, "by" is another meaning and makes much more sense. *Videntur* is plural, so it clearly must refer to *muri Romani et porta Capena*. I think I understand you, though. The sentence would be accurately stated as "the Roman wall and gate of Capena are seen by him", then?

Comment: @Adam: Correct! Add *iam* "now, already", and make "wall" plural.

Answer (score 5):

*Eō* here is the ablative singular masculine of *is, ea, id*, "he/she/it".

The other important thing to note is that the verb is *passive*—in other words, the subject in the nominative is the thing being seen, and the person doing the seeing *can be* in the ablative with *ā/ab*.

So in the nominative, the *murī Rōmānī et porta Capena* are being seen; *ab eō* refers back to a masculine singular noun. Depending on the context, the walls and gate might be seen *by* Medus (a person), or seen *from* Medus (a city); the sentence itself doesn't let you distinguish between these.

Comment: The other sentences around this one provide the context that Medus is a person rather than city. I think what is strange to me is splitting the two objects with the subject and verb.